# Brute forcing an encryption key in Java

Tags: java, encryption

This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, and I'm pretty new to Java programming. I have an assignment in my programming class to brute force an encryption key.

Essentially, the code takes a message and encrypts it with a random encryption key of unspecified length x. This random encryption key has characters from the ASCII table between 31 and 128. It then encrypts the data:

```
main_engine.set_unencrypted_message("This message will be encrypted.");
String random_key = main_engine.generate_random_encryption_key_of_length(x);
main_engine.set_encryption_key(random_key);
main_engine.encrypt_data();
```

Essentially, my task is to brute force the encryption key (without accessing the message or key, and also not creating a new method). x is also unknown, as I mentioned before. Here's an example of how this would be done if x were known to be 1. I am aware of how this should be done for any fixed number:

```
outerloop: for (char i = 32; i < 128; i++) {
  String attemptedKey = String.valueOf(i);
  if (main_engine.attempt_to_decrypt_data_with_key(attemptedKey)) {
    System.out.println("The encryption key is " + attemptedKey);
    break outerloop;
  }
}
```

Or, if I used one of the methods within main_engine, ascii_to_string, which takes in an array of integers:

```
outerloop2: for (int i = 32; i < 128; i++) {
  int[] array = new int[1];
  array[0] = i;
  String attemptedKey = main_engine.ascii_to_string(array);
  if (main_engine.attempt_to_decrypt_data_with_key(attemptedKey)) {
    System.out.println("The encryption key is " + attemptedKey);
    break outerloop2;
  }
}
```

A few other methods exist, namely string_to_ascii, which takes in a string and returns an array of integers. Processing time is not an issue, as this is merely a demo. My main issue that I was wondering about is how I would go about brute forcing the encryption key if x were unknown (the length of the encryption key were above 1 and somewhere between 1 and 10). I am mostly wondering how I would increase the amount of characters each run.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You can't brute-force an encryption key if you can't access any messages.  Indeed, you also need to know both the plain-text and encrypted versions of the message (and the encryption scheme) to be sure that you have correctly brute-forced the key.

Comment: I should specify that the attempt_to_decrypt_data_with_key method does access the message, but I personally am not allowed to access the message within this snippet.

Comment: Do you know how to brute force it for x = 1? Do you know how to do it for x = 2? ... Do you know how to do it for x = 100?

Comment: Yes, I do. Just not sure how to do it for an unspecified x.

Comment: "encryption key has characters [...] between 31 and 128" -> that means that your loop is incorrect, it should be `for (char i = 32; i <= 127; i++)`

Comment: I think you will have to try it for each x.

Comment: If x is unknown then you'll have to generate 97! (permutations of all the chars 32-127). And you'll have to feed all those permutations to `attempt_to_decrypt_data_with_key`. To speed up you can place most frequently occurring chars first in the array like `0123abcd..xyz`.

Comment: I highly recommend that you follow common Java naming conventions (that is use PascalCase for class names, and camelCase for fields, variables, methods, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

> My main issue that I was wondering about is how I would go about brute forcing the encryption key if x were unknown (the length of the encryption key were above 1 and somewhere between 1 and 100).

Well ... if the engine (i.e. the algorithm) is a "black box", you would step through all of the possible key lengths one at a time, and try all possible keys with that length.

Depending on the "alphabet" for the keys, this could take an impossibly long time; i.e. `O(size(Alphabet)**key_length)`.  So your teacher probably expects your code to heuristically limit the keyspace to (say) words in a dictionary.

(This sounds like an exercise for a crypto or "white hat" hacking course.  If so, they should have explained the basics principles of brute-force attacks to you.)